# Suggestions of mobile alternatives to a horizontal multiple dropdown filter system

Tags: touch-screen, filter, mobile-web, faceted-search

I am currently working on mobile/responsive facelift to an old static website.

The original site uses a number of drop down menus arranged in a horizontal bar to allow the selection of multiple filters at the same time.  Below the filters is a product grid that shows/hides products based on the selected filters.

[image: A wireframe of the current implementation]

Can anyone suggest any good mobile-friendly alternative strategies for multi-filtering on smart phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this design pattern article by Smashing Magazine:

http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/10/ui-patterns-for-mobile-apps-search-sort-filter/

Head down to the Filter section to see the different filter design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Take tips from http://www.futureshop.ca/ try out their site on your phone. Just put on your jacket because you might get blown away by how easy it is too search.

ie. Hierarchy searching. Biggest to smallest category (can stop and search in between)

Comment: Future Shop on mobile may have something to recommend it but only sort of uses hierarchical searching. You can search by word then narrow by various criteria (Web Only, Refurbished, Brands, etc.). "Categories" **is** one of those criteria but the UX is sort of terrible — you choose a category and the page refreshes but gives you no indication that clicking "Categories" will let you choose a sub category of the one you've just chosen. I don't find their overall UX very good, either. I'm curious what you like about it.